# Related rates with a cone

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out the rate the water level increases in a conical tank that is 3 m height, 2 m radius at top and water flows in at $2\text{m} ^3 / \text{minute}$

I know that

$$(1/3) \pi r^2 h = V$$

$$4 \pi = V$$

or at 2 seconds the volume of the water is $8.37758$

so now I have

$$(1/3) \pi r^2 h * dh/dt = V * dV/dt$$

which gives an incorrect answer, I am not sure if I use t = 2 volume and height or what.

Comment: So do you have an initial condition that $V = 4 \pi $ when $t = 2$?

Comment: Parentheses, please.  Some would read the first equation with everything in the denominator.  Either $(1/3)\pi r^2h$ or $\pi  r^2h/3$ or $\frac {\pi r^2h}3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By similar triangles, observe that:
$$
\dfrac{h}{3}=\dfrac{r}{2} \iff r=\dfrac{2h}{3}
$$
Hence, substituting into the formula for the volume of a cone will help us to avoid product rule:
$$
V=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi \left(\dfrac{2h}{3}\right)^2h = \dfrac{4\pi}{27}h^3
$$
Differentiating each side with respect to $t$ yields:
$$
\dfrac{dV}{dt} = \dfrac{4\pi}{27}(3h^2)\dfrac{dh}{dt} = \dfrac{4\pi}{9}h^2\dfrac{dh}{dt} \iff \boxed{\dfrac{dh}{dt} = \dfrac{9}{4\pi h^2}\dfrac{dV}{dt}}
$$
Since we know that $dV/dt = 2$, we simply need to plug in the height at the specific instant in time that the question is asking for into the final equation, and we are done. If the radius is given instead, simply multiply it by $3/2$ to convert to a height.

---

**EDIT:** Alright, here's my MS Paint skills. Hopefully this diagram explains where the similar triangles came from:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what similar triangles means or where those numbers come from or why that would be useful.

Comment: @Jordan:  Similar triangles are ones that have the same angles.  The sides are in proportion, but the overall size can be different.  If you slice the water with a vertical plane through the centerline, you will get a triangle.  As the cone fills, that triangle gets larger, but all the versions have the same angles and are similar.  That is where he gets the first line.

Comment: I still don't follow where h/3 = r/2 came from, what do those numbers represent?

Comment: @Jordan I've edited in a diagram. Note that $h$ and $r$ are the height and radius of the **water**, while $3$ and $2$ are the height and radius of the **tank**.

Comment: Thank you I understand that, it is really simple once I realized that the top line was basically saying 1 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

The rate of increase depends on the depth.  As you say, $V=\frac 13 \pi r^2 h$.  The calculation of the tank volume is not useful.  Then $\frac {dV}{dt}=2=\frac 13\pi(2rh\frac {dr}{dt}+r^2\frac {dh}{dt})$ using the product rule.  Now the dimensions of the cone give you $\frac {dr}{dh}$.  Can you use that to combine the two terms in the last parentheses?

Comment: No, why wouldn't the area be a useful calculation? When I get the derivative am I not left with $\frac{dv}{dh} * v = \frac{dh}{dt} * h *c$?

Comment: @Jordan:  It is not useful because the tank need not be full.  What you want is the slope of the side.